# Keras: how to output learning rate onto tensorboard

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I added a callback to decay the learning rate:

```
 keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=100, 
                                   verbose=0, mode='auto',epsilon=0.00002, cooldown=20, min_lr=0)
```

Here is my tensorboard callback:

```
keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./graph/rank{}'.format(hvd.rank()), histogram_freq=10, batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                            write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=False)
```

I want to make sure the learning rate scheduler has kicked in during training, so I want to output the learning rate onto tensorboard. But I can not find where I can set it.

I also checked the optimizer api, but no luck.

```
keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
```

How can I output the learning rate to tensorboad?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[According to the author of Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9168#issuecomment-359901128), the *proper* way is to subclass the `TensorBoard` callback:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

class LRTensorBoard(TensorBoard):
    # add other arguments to __init__ if you need
    def __init__(self, log_dir, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(log_dir=log_dir, **kwargs)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        logs.update({'lr': K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr)})
        super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
```

Then pass it as part of the `callbacks` argument to `model.fit` (credit [Finncent Price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127214/keras-how-to-output-learning-rate-onto-tensorboard/50040233?noredirect=1#comment96356387_50040233)):

```
model.fit(x=..., y=..., callbacks=[LRTensorBoard(log_dir="/tmp/tb_log")])
```

Comment: Note that @alkamid's answer is for python 3, if you are in python 2, you'll need to pass the CHILD class name and the current instance to super.  For this particular example `super()` -> `super(LRTensorBoard,self)` works.  Answer explaining this syntactic difference can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633889/typeerror-super-does-not-take-key-word-arguments

Comment: Instructions for how to use this callback in Keras inside the fit method of your model  are as follows.  Supply a list of callbacks to the callbacks variable like so: `model.fit(x=something,y=something,callbacks=[LRTensorboard(log_dir='path_to_log_dir')])`

Comment: `logs = logs or {}; logs.update(lr=K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr))`
this is better, cause logs, could be None

Comment: I would add 
`
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # add other arguments to __init__ if you need
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
`
for the function not to block other arguments to tensorboard.

Comment: @Khan I'm not sure where the `logs=None` convention is coming from, but Keras/TensorFlow tutorials seem to be using it.

Comment: This is way better than what [the official docs suggest](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras#logging_custom_scalars). If I would follow that and would want to play with different decays, I'd have to write own impls of each scheduler.

Comment: Although the approach seems legit; I get the following error before the training start ```AlreadyExistsError? another profiler already in use```

Answer (score 12):

Note that with the current nightly version of tf (2.5 - probably earlier) learning rates using [LearningRateSchedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule) are automatically added to tensorboard's logs. The following solution is only necessary if you're adapting the learning rate some other way - e.g. via [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau) or [LearningRateScheduler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler) (different to [LearningRateSchedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule)) callbacks.

While extending `tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` is a viable option, I prefer composition over subclassing.

```py
class LearningRateLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._supports_tf_logs = True

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if logs is None or "learning_rate" in logs:
            return
        logs["learning_rate"] = self.model.optimizer.lr
```

This allows us to compose multiple similar callbacks, and use the logged learning rate in multiple other callbacks (e.g. if you add a [CSVLogger](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/CSVLogger) it should also write the learning rate values to file).

Then in `model.fit`

```py
model.fit(
    callbacks=[
        LearningRateLogger(),
        # other callbacks that update `logs`
        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(path),
        # other callbacks that use updated logs, e.g. CSVLogger
    ],
    **kwargs
)
```

Comment: Works in TF 2.6 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You gave the optimizer's code twice, instead of TensorBoard Callback. Anyway, I didn`t find the way to display the learning rate on TensorBoard. 
I am plotting it after the training finished, taking data from History object:

```
nb_epoch = len(history1.history['loss'])
learning_rate=history1.history['lr']
xc=range(nb_epoch)
plt.figure(3,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,learning_rate)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('learning rate')
plt.title('Learning rate')
plt.grid(True)
plt.style.use(['seaborn-ticks'])
```

The chart looks like this:
[LR plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riNdR.png)

Sorry, that is not exactly what you are asking about, but perhaps could help.

Comment: sorry for the error. your solution is good, but don't work for me if I want monitor a training process that will take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

```
class XTensorBoard(TensorBoard):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # get values
        lr = float(K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr))
        decay = float(K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.decay))
        # computer lr
        lr = lr * (1. / (1 + decay * epoch))
        K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, lr)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        logs['lr'] = K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)
        super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

callbacks_list = [XTensorBoard('./logs')]
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

[lr curve in tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edcps.png)

Comment: Code only answers are really discouraged. Please provide explanation what you are doing too!

Answer (score 0):

For tensorflor 2.5 if you have some custom Learning Rate Scheduler:

```
class LearningRateLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
def __init__(self, log_dir):
    super().__init__()
    self._supports_tf_logs = True
    self.log_dir = log_dir
    
def set_model(self, model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    self.model = model                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    self.sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
    self.writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(self.log_dir)

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    if logs is None or "learning_rate" in logs:
        return
    logs["learning_rate"] = self.model.optimizer.lr
    logs.update({'learning_rate': self.model.optimizer.lr})
    self._write_logs(logs, epoch)
    
def _write_logs(self, logs, index):

    with self.writer.as_default():                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        for name, value in logs.items():                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            if name in ['batch', 'size']:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                continue                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            if isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
                tf.summary.scalar(name, value.item(), step=index)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            else:
                tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=index)
    
        self.writer.flush()
```

Then for calling the callback in your model.fit:

```
model.fit(x=..., y=..., callbacks=[LearningRateLogger(log_dir="/path/to/folder/where/tensorboard/is/logging")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the `ReduceLROnPlateau` callback comes **before** the `TensorBoard` callback in the list of callbacks. Then you will see an `lr` metric logged to TensorBoard every epoch.