# Tensorboard plot ReduceLROnPlateau

Tags: python, tensorflow, learning-rate

I keep failing to plot my learning rate in tensorboard because I am using the ReduceLROnPlateau as following:

```py
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=results_path, histogram_freq=1)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.5, verbose=1,
                              patience=100, min_lr=0.000001)
callbacks = [tensorboard_callback, reduce_lr]
# Compile VAE
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=kl_reconstruction_loss,  metrics=["mse", metric_KL,binary_crossentropy])

# Train autoencoder
history = vae.fit(x_train, x_train, 
                  epochs = no_epochs, 
                  batch_size = batch_size, 
                  validation_data=(x_test,x_test,),
                  callbacks=callbacks)
```

After that I run this to plot the custom metrics to tensorboard log:

```
for epoch in range(len(history.history['mse'])):
    with train_summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('metric_KL', history.history['metric_KL'][epoch], step=epoch)
```

With that setup. How can I plot my learning rate without writing my own custom ReduceLROnPlateau?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to overwrite the `TensorBoard` callback.

You can see here how you can do that: [Keras: how to output learning rate onto tensorboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127214/keras-how-to-output-learning-rate-onto-tensorboard).

You just need to adapt the code with the imports for `tensorflow.keras` instead of plain `keras`.